# XCTestCase - how to delete app in setup method

Tags: swift, xctest

I am writing unit tests for my Swift application and I would like to delete the app in between each test case for certain suites. I already have a script action set up that uninstalls the app before the whole suite runs. But I have not found a way to be able to delete the app off the simulator in between each `test` invocation. Is there a way to do this?

What I want is:

```swift
import XCTest
@testable import My_App

class MyTests: XCTestCase {

  override func setUpWithError throws () {
    magic("xcrun simctl uninstall booted ${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}")
  }
  
  func testTheThings() {
    // test runs with a completely fresh slate...
  }
}
```

Please note that this is **unit testing** and not UI testing - so I don't think I can have the test delete the app from the Springboard, which is what I otherwise do in my UI tests to give each test a clean slate.